# What's the difference between Brand and Organization in Schema.org?

Tags: ecommerce, schema.org

What is the difference between a `Brand` and an `Organization`?

If you have a clothing website, and you sell clothes and shoes from popular names like Adidas, Reebok, Puma, etc. When displaying these names in a list would you mark them up as a `Brand` or an `Organization`?

Would `Brand` be the name that you are selling or would it be a specific line of shoes or line of jackets (for example) of that company?

So if the user clicks on my Adidas link, it goes to a details page with a short description about Adidas and a list of all the products on the website from Adidas. So is Adidas marked up as a `Brand` or an `Organization`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference might become clearer for cases where the organization name is not identical to the brand name.

For example, consider the company *Lenovo* (`Organization`) which owns the brand *ThinkPad* (`Brand`). A specific *ThinkPad* product (`Product`) manufactured by *Lenovo* could be marked up like this:

```html
<article vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="Product">
  <h1 property="name">ThinkPad X60</h1>
  <div property="manufacturer" typeof="Organization">
    <span property="name">Lenovo</span>
  </div>
  <div property="brand" typeof="Brand">
    <span property="name">ThinkPad</span>
  </div>
</article>
```

If you want to display both, the manufacturer and the brand, you could of course use the same structure also in cases where the organization/manufacturer name is identical to (one of) their brand names. Albeit named the same, a brand and its owner are still separate entities.

To prevent the visible duplication, you could use `meta`/`link` elements to hide one of the instances (in the case of JSON-LD, this is not relevant, of course), or you could consider using both types together (but that *might* be problematic, depending on syntax/consumer).

If you want to provide more data about one of these entities, you have to consider what exactly you are talking about. For example, a `Brand` can’t have a `PostalAddress` etc. Given that the [`Brand`](http://schema.org/Brand) type has only few properties defined, you can’t provide that much data about it anyway.

Comment: Your opinion on @Andrew Lott's answer? Lots of clothing websites have a brands section where they list the names of the organizations as the brands.

Comment: @BrendanVogt: I guess his answer and mine come to the same conclusion: which type to choose depends on the information you want to provide. -- Clothing websites: I’d say these would be `Brand` item then; but without seeing an example, it’s hard to say.

Comment: For clothing/products, I don't see much value in including `Organization` in the microdata; if you're buying Tylenol, then the company who manufactured it doesn't really matter. In other cases it may even confuse things; when buying a Maytag appliance you don't need to see Whirlpool just because they own the Maytag brand.

Answer (score 4):

Usually `Organization` represents a company itself (school, NGO, corporation, club, etc.) whereas a `Brand` represents a product or service. In many cases these may be the same, e.g. Adidas; but not always, e.g. Tylenol, a brand sold by the organization/company Johnson & Johnson.

So, which you should use depends on what you're writing about. If you are selling Adidas shoes then Adidas is the `Brand`, but if you're writing an article about the company's profits then Adidas would be the `Organization`.

Answer (score 1):

Unor has given a great answer but I'd also like to add something -

Schema.org gives this simple definition of [Brand](https://schema.org/Brand) from markups perspective and this definition seems very logical.

> A brand is a name used by an organization or business person for
>   labeling a product, product group, or similar.

So in your case, every shoe which is being sold belongs to a brand. While marking up that content you must specify the brand value as *itemprop* and parent property *itemtype* as an organization. For Example:

```
 <span itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
   <span itemprop="name">Addidas</span>
 </span>
```

For more properties of Brand schema, please check this [link](https://schema.org/Brand).